# jquery invoke .change without user action but by .val change

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a text box that has its value changed from a function. How would I create a function based on the value changing from the script and not the user "clicking" or manually changing the value?

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ShippingCost').live({
        change: function() { 

alert('changed!');
        }
     });
});
```

But it only works when a user changes it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call the change yourself in the code which updates the value:

```
$('#ShippingCost').val("something")
                  .change();  // this will execute the change code
```

Changing values through javascript does not fire events.

Comment: So I would set the value to say, 0, then call the change in the original function that changes the value and have this function?

Comment: You will still have the code you posted originally which will execute whenever the change event fires.  Then anywhere that you update that value in your code, you would call `.change()` to fire the change event.

Comment: That works fine, I just put $('#ShippingCost').change(); at the end if the function that changes the value. THanks!

Comment: Just as an aside, the shortform of James' example could also be written as: `$('#ShippingCost').val("something").change();`

Comment: @TerryR is correct.  In real usage you should chain or at least assign the jquery object to a variable rather than querying twice.  I had expanded it to make clear what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

You need to trigger the event manually:

`$('#ShippingCost').trigger('change');`

Answer (score -2):

I'd just blur the input, so the change triggers on its own.

```
$('#ShippingCost').val('changed value').blur();
```

Comment: Although this could work, I wouldn't recommend this method as it can affect other areas of the page that may rely on a `blur()` event.  There are direct ways of triggering the event (as shown in other answers), this would be considered more of a work-around.

Comment: And wouldn't this only work if the input already has focus?  would it even work then?

Comment: The thought of impersonating user actions scares me, I don't even want to know if it works.

Comment: @TerryR Interesting, I guess I've got some code to change. :P

Comment: @MetalFrog don't we all... :)

Comment: @TerryR Yup, unless we stop learning, which isn't a good idea.