# Launch event on value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I made simple date picker using JavaScript and jQuery. After choosing date it is shown in input box. This input box is not launching change event, probably because it was changed using JavaScript. Is there any way to launch this event, or to make custom one?

Comment: Did you use a datepicker plugin (such as the one from jQuery UI) or implement your own?

Comment: it should be launch the onchange event. Please post ur code

Comment: im changing value using `$( "#" + calName + "_date" ).val( cal.actualdate + ". " + (cal.month+1) + ". " + cal.year );` It is working after I added `$( "#" + calName + "_date" ).change();`(Thx Kane Black)

Comment: bind the onchange functionality with live function http://api.jquery.com/live/ and it would be helpful if u show some code

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery invoke .change without user action but by .val change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437125/jquery-invoke-change-without-user-action-but-by-val-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this code after you assign new value:

```
$('input').change();
```

Comment: Would be better to fire the event on the specific input, rather than ALL inputs.

Comment: @SpaceBison, it was just a generic answer. I assumed that Uriel_SVK knows how to assign change event to specific input field.

Answer (score 1):

.change just points to the .on function inside jquery, so it's better to use the .on directly.

```
$('#inputID').on('change', function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input#yourInputId").change();
```

or

```
$("input#yourInputId").trigger("change");
```

Should do the trick. Replace the #yourInputId with an id that represents the `ID="abc"` part of your HTML for the textbox

- Be aware of potential browser irregularities or lack of support for change events - behaviour may vary, particularly in older browsers.

Comment: jQuery normalize the change-behavior for IE6>

Answer (score 0):

There is a change and an input event. The first fires after an input changed and lost focus. The latter fires immediately when the input changes. However there are no events that fire after programatically changing an input.

If you have control over the code that changes your inputs you can of course trigger the events manually like described in the other answers.